# Error while getting data from existing table using EF6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am getting the error saying "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'DTP'" while accessing the data from existing table in Database . I am using EF6 . Steps that I followed are 
1)   added reference to the Entity framework in the project. 
2) in web.config added the connections string as

```
<add name="OrderSummaryDatabaseContext" connectionString="data source=XYZ--D1;initial catalog=DTP_Table;user id=xyz;password=xyz;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

3)  defined the data context class as

```
public class OrderSummaryDatabaseContext :DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    }
```

4)  Defined the document class as below

```
public class Document
{
public int id { get; set; }

public int clientId { get; set; }

public int? reference { get; set; }

public string format { get; set; }

public string imagePath { get; set; }

public DateTime dateReceived { get; set; }

public DateTime? dateReported { get; set; }

public int? addedByUserId { get; set; }

public short? active { get; set; }

public DateTime? lastChangedDate { get; set; }
}
```

5)  In my data layer getting the details as

```
    public void GetImageData()
    {
        int orderId = 1426;
        try
        {
            using (var db = new OrderSummaryDatabaseContext())
            {
                var result = db.Documents.Where(x => x.id == orderId).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }   
    }
```

but I am getting the error saying ""CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'DTP'". Please help me with this, I don't want to use the EDMX file. I want to do it without that

Comment: The error tells you the problem, what more help do you need?

Comment: Table from which I am trying to access the data , already exists. I am new to EF6 so need help what needs to be done for that. As table already exists I simply want to select data from that table. why I am getting error for create table where I am simply selecting the data from existing table. Thanks Please help me understand that.

Comment: FYI, this isn't part of the question but in C# it's standard to use PascalCase for class properties instead of CamelCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not planning on using `CodeFirst`, you should add this to the constructor of the context:

```
public OrderSummaryDatabaseContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<OrderSummaryDatabaseContext>(null);
}
```

This will stop EntityFramework from trying to create tables for you. I'm not 100% sure what is happening here, but what it sounds like is EntityFramework is trying to create the tables for you based on your code and since you have already created the table it is failing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response , by adding the line of code in the constructor it worked perfectly fine. marking this as as answer